# JFileChooser does not work outside of main method

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I'm currently started with Java and I'm writing a program witch at the end creates a File and saves it. i'd like to use the JFileChooser to make the user to choose the directory where the file shall be saved.

I created a class to use the JFileChooser and to save the file accordingly.

to test it i let it run in a test class in the main method and everything works.

to use it in the program I put the code into the real class (csvSaver into the saveCsv method).
This class i open from another class (Vermietungen) with:
csvSaver.saveCsv(args);

now it doesn't work anymore... why? i don't understand... I don't even get en Error. just nothing happens...

here the code from the first Class (I call the class csvSaver in the switch under "Rechnungen":
`enter code here`

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class Vermietungen 
    {
    public enum AccountType {Erfassen, Bearbeiten, Lesen, Löschen, Rechnungen}
    public static void vermiet (String[] args) 
    {
    AccountType[] choicesI = {AccountType.Erfassen, AccountType.Bearbeiten, AccountType.Lesen, AccountType.Löschen, AccountType.Rechnungen };
    AccountType selectVer = (AccountType) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Was möchten Sie machen?", "Vermietungenverwaltung", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, choicesI, choicesI[4]);

    if (selectVer!=null)
    {
        switch (selectVer) 
        {
            case Erfassen:
                selectVer = null;
                VerErfassen.neueVermietung(args);
                break;

            case Bearbeiten:
                selectVer = null;
                VerBearbeiten.verChange(args);
                break;

            case Lesen:
                selectVer = null;
                VerLesen.verRead(args);
                break;

            case Löschen:
                selectVer = null;
                VerLöschen.verDelete(args);
                break;

            case Rechnungen:
                selectVer = null;
                csvSaver.saveCsv(args);
                break;

            default:
                selectVer = null;
                Hauptmenü.hauptmenü(args);
                break;
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        Hauptmenü.hauptmenü(args);
    }
}
```

And this is the code with the JFileChooser:

```
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javax.swing.Box;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    public class csvSaver 
    {
        public enum AccountType {Monat, Jahr}
        public static void saveCsv(String[] args) 
        {
        String dateinameVer = "VermietungVerwaltung.txt";
        File verFile = new File(dateinameVer);

    boolean tester = false;
    try 
    {   JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Wo möchten Sie die CSV-Datei abspeichern?");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        {
            JTextField aField = new JTextField(4);
            JTextField bField = new JTextField(2);
            JPanel csvPanel = new JPanel();

            csvPanel.add(new JLabel("Jahr"));
            csvPanel.add(aField);
            csvPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(1)); // a spacer
            csvPanel.add(new JLabel("Monat"));
            csvPanel.add(bField);

            int csvResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, csvPanel,"Von welchem Monat/Jahr möchten Sie die Rechnungsdaten?", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (csvResult == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
            {
                String csvJahr = aField.getText();
                String csvMonat = bField.getText();

                File csvFile = new File (csvJahr + "_" + csvMonat + "_Rechnungen.txt");
                System.out.println(csvFile);

                String verId = "";
                String verInId = "";    
                String verInName = "";
                String verKuId = "";
                String verKuVorN = "";
                String verKuName = "";  
                String startT = "";
                String startM = "";
                String startJ = "";
                String endT = "";
                String endM = "";
                String endJ = "";
                String preis = "";
                String dauer = "";

                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(csvFile, true);
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
                    Scanner sucher = new Scanner(verFile);
                    sucher.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
                    boolean verFinder = false;

                    //File durchgehen:
                    while(sucher.hasNext())
                    {   
                        //Linie auslesen:
                        verId = sucher.next();
                        verInId = sucher.next();
                        verInName = sucher.next();
                        verKuId = sucher.next();
                        verKuVorN = sucher.next();
                        verKuName = sucher.next();
                        startT = sucher.next();
                        startM = sucher.next();
                        startJ = sucher.next();
                        endT = sucher.next();
                        endM = sucher.next();
                        endJ = sucher.next();
                        preis = sucher.next();
                        dauer = sucher.next();

                        //entspricht Linie dem Suchbegriff? wenn nein:
                        if (startJ.equals(csvJahr)) 
                        {   
                            if (startM.equals(csvMonat)) 
                            {
                            //in neue Datei kopieren:
                            pw.println(verId + "," + verInId + "," + verInName + "," + verKuId + "," + verKuVorN + "," + verKuName + "," + startT + "," + startM + "," + startJ + "," + endT + "," + endM + "," + endJ + "," + preis + "," + dauer);
                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Das CSV-File wurde in: " + chooser.getSelectedFile() + " gespeichert.", "Gespeichert!", 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    sucher.close();
                    pw.flush();
                    pw.close();
            }
            else
            {
                 Hauptmenü.hauptmenü(args);
                  tester = true;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            Hauptmenü.hauptmenü(args);
            tester = true;
        }
    }catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (tester ==false)
    {
        Hauptmenü.hauptmenü(args);
    }
    }
    }
```

So in the JFileChooser never opens...
(it opens if i copy/paste this exact code into the main method...

Who can help me? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried to put some Sysouts between the lines to see which parts of the code are executed?

Comment: none if your variables seem to be initialized. Also please don't use german at all, english is much easier to understand in programming. also you should read up on the java naming convention

Comment: Hi! Please post a [mcve] - a minimal piece of code that demonstrates your problem. You can and should remove all the code that is not related to your problem. Also, please use an IDE to format your code so that it has consistent indenting, and so that other people can read it.

Comment: The argument to `showOpenDialog` is the parent window, and even if I'm not sure about that, I don't think a window can be parent of itself. If you don't have any other window, consider using `null` instead of `chooser`.

Comment: it's unclear from where you call `vermiet`. More reason to see an MCVE.